# Trying to make table vertical

Tags: html

I'm just trying to get some help making the table in vertical alignment. My problem is that it shifted the td text to the left.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web Colors</title>
</head>
<style>
table,td, th{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border: double;
}
td{
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
<body>
<table style="width: 60%; margin: 0px auto;">
<tr>
<th>Web Colors</th>
    <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#ffffcc;">
        #ffffcc
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:#66ffff;">
        #66ffff
    </td>
    <td  style="background-color:#ffff22;">
        #ffff22
    </td>
    <td  style="background-color:#999999;">
        #999999
    </td>
    <td  style="background-color:#ff0000;">
        #ff0000
    </td>
    <td  style="background-color:#ff8429;">
        #ff8429
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is what it should look like but it doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhyGA.png)

[This is what it actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsFaV.png)

[This is what it looks like but it needs the colors to fill the table and the text to be the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgyDZ.png)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!
Hope it helps :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   
<HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web Colors</title>
</head>
<style>
table, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border: double;
}
td {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid gray;
}

</style>
<body>
<table style="width: 60%; margin: 0px auto;">
<tr>
<th>Web Colors</th>
    <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#ffffcc;">
        #ffffcc
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:#66ffff;">
        #66ffff
    </td>
    <td  style="background-color:#ffff22;">
        #ffff22
    </td>
    <td  style="background-color:#999999;">
        #999999
    </td>
    <td  style="background-color:#ff0000;">
        #ff0000
    </td>
    <td  style="background-color:#ff8429;">
        #ff8429
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need each color on its own table row then your missing some code

for each row you need:

```
<tr> <!-- Start of row -->
<td>Color 1</td>
</tr>  <!-- End of row -->
```

so your table code should look like:

```
<table>
<tr> <!-- 1st row -->
<td>Color 1</td>
</tr>  <!-- End of 1st row -->
<tr> <!-- 2nd row -->
<td>Color 2</td>
</tr>  <!-- End of 2nd row -->
<tr> <!-- 3rd row -->
<td>Color 3</td>
</tr>  <!-- End of 3rd row -->
</table>
```